# Using the Hygieia Jira collector - Jira dependencies

Tags: hygieia

I have Hygieia and the Jira collector compiled and running.  almost.  The Jira collector is making a call to https://url.example.com/jira/rest/tempo-teams/1/team which returns a 404.  It looks like this id Tempo-Teams add-on which I guess we don't have.  Our org doesn't use teams.  Can we use this collector without this teams module? Commenting out the custom field definition in the properties file

```
#############################################################################
# In Jira, your instance will have its own custom field created for 'team'
# This field allows you to specify that data field for your instance
# of Jira.  Note:  You can retrieve your instance's team ID field name via the following URI where your
# queried user story issue has team set on it; your custom field name describes the
# team value you expect to see:
# https://[your-jira-domain-name]/rest/api/2/issue/[some-issue-name]
#############################################################################
#feature.jiraTeamFieldName=
```

appears to make no difference.  In the UI, the team name is a requirement.  How can I NOT use this module without having to munge around the java code?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to set the following in the application.properties file:

```
feature.jiraTeamFieldName=
feature.jiraBoardAsTeam=true
```

This will change the collector to operate in Board mode instead of Teams mode.